# Daily horoscope for zodiac signs

Tags: code-golf

Code a daily horoscope for the 12 zodiac signs, it needs to be self-sustained (no external ressources), quite randomized but fixed by zodiac sign for each day.

It needs to extract three "variables" from 1 to 3 :

1. love
2. work
3. money

Each one ranked from 1 to 3.

Ex. of variables that can be used (vars fixed for a day or more, can be extended) :

- Year
- Month
- Day
- Day of week
- Math.PI
- Zodiac signs order (from 1 to 12)

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355525/coding-a-daily-horoscope-algorithm

Comment: Requirements are fairly unclear

Comment: @Paul: Thanks for the pointer, but I think that in this epoch code golf is off-topic on Stack Overflow, so this version takes precedence.

Comment: Welcome to CodeGolf.SE! As it stands your task is highly underspecified and in danger of being closed. You might want to examine [the tag wiki for code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) or some of [our more popular tasks](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=closed%3a0). In the future you can get help in [the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/336/78) or on [the puzzle lab chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/307) before your task goes live.

Comment: Please make an effort to bring this more in-line with our usual level of specification. There is nothing intrinsically wrong with this task, you just have said *what* the task is yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Python, 106 chars

```
import time,zlib
for i in range(12):n=zlib.crc32(time.strftime('%%Y%%j%d'%i));print 1+n%3,1+n/3%3,1+n/9%3
```

Calculates the CRC of a string made up of the current year, day of year, and zodiac sign.  Grabs some bits of the result for the horoscope.

Answer (score 0):

From SO : "Add year+month*11+day*13+sign, feed this in as a seed to your local PRNG. After that you can either generate one "next random number" mod 27, extracting your 3 3s from there, or run it three times mod 3."